# Self host osm tiles

Tags: openstreetmap

I want to host osm tiles and styles by my self on my server. I got a really nice style here

https://github.com/CartoDB/basemap-styles#1-web-raster-basemaps

It's free for use under observation of the license requirements. But i don't know how to make the next step. 
I allready implemented the map on my site with using leaflet and this code (just the tile implementation part)

```
L.tileLayer(' url ', {}).addTo(map);
```

How to go on to replace this hosted version to go on to self hosted one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set up your own tile server by following the steps at [switch2osm](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/). This is an rather advanced step and requires a sufficient powerful system with fast storage and large memory. At least if you want to server tiles for the whole world. Smaller extracts have lower requirements.

Alternatively switch to vector tiles, e.g. [Mapbox GL](https://www.mapbox.com/help/define-mapbox-gl/). It allows you to influence the rendering style without having to set up a large infrastructure for serving the data.

Comment: Okay, thats a good suggestion. Is it possible to use leaflet with vector tiles? The mapbox GL seems not that editable as leaflet.

Comment: According to Mapbox, [Mapbox.js](https://www.mapbox.com/help/how-web-apps-work/#mapboxjs) "extends the popular Leaflet.js library". Alternatively there seems to be an experimental [Mapbox GL Leaflet](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-leaflet) project. Note that I don't have any experience with this.

Comment: Okay thanks. The Mapbox.js is just a raster tile framework as leaflet, but can be handled together (in some ways). But the Mapbox GL Leaflet is the way i will go on i think.

Comment: This answer makes it sound as if you cannot self-host OSM vector tiles?

Comment: @DouglasGaskell Well, there are multiple vector-tile solutions for OSM. See [vector tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Vector_tiles) in the OSM wiki. I'm sure that you can host some of them yourself.

Comment: Do we have any opensource alternatives for this?

Comment: @SathishKumar Yes, see https://community.openstreetmap.org/t/osm-vector-tile-capabilities-and-advancements-as-of-2023/103620